# Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'void' Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

i create a function for stram audio in angular :

```
 private streamObservable(url) {
    new Observable(observer => {
      // Play audio
      this.audioObj.src = url;
      this.audioObj.load();
      this.audioObj.play();

      const handler = (event: Event) => {
        observer.next(event);
      };

      this.addEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
      return () => {
        // Stop Playing
        this.audioObj.pause();
        this.audioObj.currentTime = 0;
        // remove event listeners
        this.removeEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
      };
    });
  }
```

and when i need to using that function it show me error :

function use :

```
 playStream(url) {
    return this.streamObservable(url).pipe(takeUntil(this.stop$));
}
```

and show this error :

> Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'void'.

**whats the problem ???how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the observable from the called function.

Like - `return new Observable (observer => {`

```
 private streamObservable(url) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      // Play audio
      this.audioObj.src = url;
      this.audioObj.load();
      this.audioObj.play();

      const handler = (event: Event) => {
        observer.next(event);
      };

      this.addEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
      return () => {
        // Stop Playing
        this.audioObj.pause();
        this.audioObj.currentTime = 0;
        // remove event listeners
        this.removeEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
      };
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was a pretty simple mistake, in my case I was returning an observable but I wasn't calling the method properly. I was missing the `()` in the method call.

Original Code

```
this.service.method.pipe().subscribe();
```

Fixed Code

```
this.service.method().pipe().subscribe();
```

Comment: Is there anywhere to get a good tutorial on httpClient and Angular??  I'm using Angular 12, and there doesn't seem to be any tutorials that actually work.
A simple get() would be great.